# on duplicate key update result affecting all the rows of the table

Tags: mysql

I have a table of this structure:

```
mysql> desc securities;
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| sym             | varchar(19) | NO   | PRI |         |       |
| bqn             | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| sqn             | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| tqn             | int(11)     | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I am trying to do a select and an update within the same query, so the reason I have chosen

```
insert into securities (sym, bqn, sqn , tqn) values('ANK', 50,0,1577798) 
on duplicate key update  bqn=bqn+50 , sqn=sqn+0 , tqn=tqn+1577798;
```

When I ran the above I observed it is in fact changing the values for all the other rows also.

Is this behaviour expected? I am using MySQL Database.

Comment: how to resolve this , i even put up the where condition at the end , but its thhrowing sql syntax error .

Comment: Hard to say anything without seeing any actual existing data. Please create a working example on sqlfiddle.com

Comment: oh ok , just give me a minute

Comment: This is my link to my sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aaf91/3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle is *missing the key*, and the INSERT statement in the right panel (where it does not belong in the first place) is using different column names … **sigh**

Define the `symbol` column as `PRIMARY KEY` – and use the `VALUES()` syntax to get the values to add in the ON UPDATE part, so that you don’t have to *repeat* them every single time:

```
insert into securities
  (symbol, buyerquan, sellerquan , totaltradedquan)
  values('BANKBARODA', 73, 0, 4290270) 
  on duplicate key update  
    buyerquan=buyerquan+VALUES(buyerquan),
    sellerquan=sellerquan+VALUES(sellerquan),
    totaltradedquan=totaltradedquan+VALUES(totaltradedquan);
```

Works perfectly fine, result values are as to be expect from the input: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/21638f/1